# .NET core output type in csproj file

Tags: macos, .net-core, csproj

I have a csproj file made on a Windows machine that uses .NET SDK. I am currently using the file on a Mac and want to know what the project SDK should be for .NET Core 2.2 and want to know what the output type should be for a Mac.

Comment: Please add sample of your `csproj` file. The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The `.csproj` file is support multi-platform. You need the *sdk* that defined in `TargetFramework` and above